# Join with comma separated values in SQL Server Compact not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce, sql-server-2017

I have 2 table as below

```
CREATE TABLE [Chart]
(
   [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [Owner] NVARCHAR(100),
   [Identifier] NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
   [Title] NVARCHAR(100),
   [Type] INT NOT NULL,
   [Category] INT NOT NULL,
   [CreatedDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [ModifiedDate] DATETIME,
   [ExpireDate] DATETIME,
   [VisitCount] BIGINT NOT NULL,
   [ConfigurationId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
   [Theme] NVARCHAR(50)
);

ALTER TABLE [Chart] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Chart] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);


CREATE TABLE [SelectedTag]
(
   [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [Identifier] NVARCHAR(4000),
   [TagName] NVARCHAR(4000),
   [Description] NVARCHAR(4000),
   [EuUnit] NVARCHAR(50),
   [EuRangeLow] NVARCHAR(50),
   [EuRangeHigh] NVARCHAR(50),
   [MinStats] FLOAT,
   [MaxStats] FLOAT,
   [Min] FLOAT,
   [Max] FLOAT,
   [GroupCode] NVARCHAR(4000)
);

ALTER TABLE [SelectedTag] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SelectedTag] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
```

I tried this answer for query Tag Count and TagList for one Id it worked well in SQL Server

https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/112408/172901

```
select c.Identifier, count(c.Identifier) as TagCount, (
       select concat(',', s.TagName)  from selectedtag  as s
       where concat(',', c.identifier, ',') like '%,'+s.identifier+',%'
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'varchar(max)') as TagList
 from chart c
 group by c.Identifier
```

[image]

But with SQL Server compact Database it did not work

[image]

I use CompactView to run query with SQL compact DB

https://sourceforge.net/projects/compactview/

What issue with my query or SQL Compact issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML data type and functions are not supported by SQL Server Compact, and nested sSELECTs does not work either. Write a plain select, and perform additional processing in code.

Comment: How can I handle my query with SQL compact? Impossible?

Comment: I write query to get count only and check count condition, load more information in source code. Thank for your information

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.[Identifier]
      ,COUNT(c.[Identifier]) AS TagCount
      ,STRING_AGG(ST.[TagName], ',') AS TagList
FROM [Chart] C
INNER JOIN selectedtag ST
    ON C.[Identifier] = ST.[Identifier]
GROUP BY c.[Identifier];
```

Since, you are using SQL Server 2017, you can use [STRING_AGG](http://ansact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to concatenate strings.

Comment: @HienNguyen Does this SQL Compact support loops?

Comment: String_agg is not supported by SQL Compact